# How can i set sharp half circle background in css

Tags: html, css

[image]I am trying to put half circle background but radius in bottom not completely coming in circle....

Here is my code i have tried

```css
.main {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-top: -130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an example or image in mind?

Comment: https://codepen.io/xram/pen/thLsk might actually help

Comment: I attach my image example ...thanks

Comment: Do you want a complete half circle or something like a rectangle with circular end (something like a race-track)?

Comment: Hi.  Stack Overflow is working on a new feature [Your Reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction?cb=1).   If you have found your answer, please click on the ICON under voting.  Long-Life to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PraneetDixit I want little bit rectangle with circular....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it's working in all devices

```css
.main{
   overflow: hidden;
}
.bg {
   width:80vw;
   height:40vw;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 80vw;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 80vw;
   background-color: lightgray; 
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `svg` to make things easier. There is the `circle` element which you can include that always draws perfect circles. Place it so that only the bottom half shows and you've got a half circle.

Example:

```css
svg {
  width: 98vw;
  height: 98vw;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="0" r="50" fill="grey" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.halfCircle{
     height:45px;
     width:90px;
     border-radius: 90px 90px 0 0;
     background:green;
}
<div class="halfCircle"></div>


the bellow link has all the shape
https://paulund.co.uk/how-to-create-different-shapes-in-css
```

Comment: It's working good...but what happen when we increase the height and width at that time it's not looking perfectly....

Answer (score 0):

As per as you have told your requirements in your comment, I have this.

```css
.main {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

.bg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  /*Have reduced the width and height just for the sake of simplicity. It's completely up to you */
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-top: -130px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this solves your query.

Answer (score 0):

It is working and looking perfectly .But the width should be twice the height and the border-redious first two parameters equal to height and last parameters should be 0

```css
.halfCircle{
     height:400px;
     width:800px;
     border-radius: 400px 400px 0 0;
     background:green;
}
```